# Безопасный запуск бинарника в linux

Tags: linux, ассемблер, docker, binary, lxc

Есть ли возможность выполнить бинарник (без зависимостей), в некой более легковесной песочнице, чем виртуальная машина, при том, что бинарнику я не доверяю?

Желательно, что бы можно было ограничить доступные процессу ресурсы (диск, память, CPU, т.д.).

Копал в сторону LXC, но, как я понял, он не даёт никаких гарантий безопасности.

Comment: `Docker` более сейчас моден.

Comment: да, но Docker это обёртка над LXC

Comment: А операционка - обёртка над i/o и tcp/ip, которые являются обёртками для тактов в CPU, который является обёрткой над реализацией законов физики. Чтобы поиграть в Zuma Deluxe ты же не считаешь на абаке?

Comment: *не даёт никаких гарантий безопасности* — да, бумаги с гербовой печатью в данном случае ожидать не стоит.

Comment: а что подразумевается под безопасностью?

Comment: 1. запретить доступ к памяти других процессов.
2. запретить доступ к диску.
3. запретить доступ к сети.
4. запретить доступ к устройствам.

Вообще, нужно запустить бинарник с параметрами, и получить от него ответ. всё. Но бинарнику, кочечно мы не доверяем.

Comment: Это все lxc/докер режет без особых усилий, кроме, разве что, доступа к диску. Но по умолчанию процесс может писать только в выделенную ему область, аналогично chroot.

Answer (score 1):

Я что-то не понимаю, Вы говорите о Linux, или о виндовозе ?!
Заведите пользователя по имени test, скопируйте в его домашнюю директорию подозрительный ELF и задайте для этого пользователя лимиты по диску и ЦП. Все...

1. **запретить доступ к памяти других процессов.**
   А что - есть способ получить доступ к памяти ДРУГОГО процесса ?!
   Ну, за исключением ОБОЮДНОГО согласия по shm...
2. **запретить доступ к диску.**
   Болььше установленной квоты он не изгадит. В чужие домашние папки он не попадёт. Файл /etc/shadow не прочитает :-) Чего боитесь ?
3. **запретить доступ к сети.**
   Перед запуском ELF скажите *sudo ifconfig eth0 down*. Всё... Никакой сети!
4. **запретить доступ к устройствам**
   Если Вы не дадите пользователю test  прав root-а, то они и не будут доступны.

Comment: а что будут делать остальные процессы на хосте без сети?

Comment: А подождать 10 секунд они не могут ?  Или Ваш подозрительный ELF должен работать часами? Я понял, что Вы просто хотите проверить, что он не уронит систему...

Comment: я не автор, но запустить виртуалку для однократной проверки он смог бы, думаю.

Comment: Бинарник заэксплуатирует дыру в ядре и получит root :)

Comment: **запустить виртуалку для однократной проверки** - мне кажется, что проблема совершенно надуманная. Linux - это не виндовоз и "уложить" его очень даже не просто. Ничего "такого" этот ELF не сделает! Что-то я не слышал об успешных взломах linux-систем без участия "человеческого фактора"...

Comment: @Sergey, вы бы ознакомились с понятием "локальный эксплойт", а такое понаписали...

Comment: @0andriy Вы бы прислали мне такой "локальный эксплойт", я его честно запущу на своём компе. Если он уложит мой комп - я Вам плачу $100, если нет - Вы мне... Договорились ? :-)

Comment: Детский сад. Будьте чуть серьёзней.

Comment: @0andriy - Т.е. у Вас нет этого самого "локального эксплойта" ? Странно... А вот в сети пишут, что это - чрезвычайно распространённая штука.  И даже есть сайты, где любой желающий их может получить... Клевещут ?